# php7.2-fpm missing sock file

Tags: php, nginx, dockerfile

I have a Docker that contains both php7.2-fpm and nginx. I'm trying to connect nginx to php7.2-fpm though socket but I get error:

```
[crit] 24#24: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.20.0.7, server: , request: "GET /health/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:"
```

Connecting through TCP works but not socket. Cannot find that file anywhere in the system.
I might be doing something wrong, been trying stuff for hours with no luck after searching all over stack overflow. It's not a user permission error.

**Here is my nginx.conf**

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
```

**Here is my www.conf**

```
;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen = /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

**Here is my Dockerfile:**

```
#
# Vendor
#
FROM composer:2.0.8 as vendor

COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock

RUN composer install \
    --ignore-platform-reqs \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins \
    --no-scripts \
    --prefer-dist

#
# PHP
#
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update

ARG ADDITIONAL_LOCALES="aa_DJ.UTF-8 UTF-8 af_ZA.UTF-8 UTF-8 an_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_AE.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_BH.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_DZ.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_EG.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_IQ.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_JO.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_KW.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_LB.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_LY.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_MA.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_OM.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_QA.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_SA.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_SD.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_SY.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_TN.UTF-8 UTF-8 ar_YE.UTF-8 UTF-8 ast_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8 be_BY.UTF-8 UTF-8 bg_BG.UTF-8 UTF-8 br_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8 bs_BA.UTF-8 UTF-8 ca_AD.UTF-8 UTF-8 ca_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8 ca_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8 ca_IT.UTF-8 UTF-8 cs_CZ.UTF-8 UTF-8 cy_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8 da_DK.UTF-8 UTF-8 de_AT.UTF-8 UTF-8 de_BE.UTF-8 UTF-8 de_CH.UTF-8 UTF-8 de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8 de_LU.UTF-8 UTF-8 el_GR.UTF-8 UTF-8 el_CY.UTF-8 UTF-8 en_AU.UTF-8 UTF-8 en_BW.UTF-8 UTF-8 en_CA.UTF-8 UTF-8 en_DK.UTF-8 UTF-8 en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8 en_HK.UTF-8 UTF-8 en_IE.UTF-8 UTF-8 en_NZ.UTF-8 UTF-8 en_PH.UTF-8 UTF-8 en_SG.UTF-8 UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 en_ZA.UTF-8 UTF-8 en_ZW.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_AR.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_BO.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_CL.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_CO.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_CR.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_DO.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_EC.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_GT.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_HN.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_MX.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_NI.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_PA.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_PE.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_PR.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_PY.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_SV.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_UY.UTF-8 UTF-8 es_VE.UTF-8 UTF-8 et_EE.UTF-8 UTF-8 eu_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8 fi_FI.UTF-8 UTF-8 fo_FO.UTF-8 UTF-8 fr_BE.UTF-8 UTF-8 fr_CA.UTF-8 UTF-8 fr_CH.UTF-8 UTF-8 fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8 fr_LU.UTF-8 UTF-8 ga_IE.UTF-8 UTF-8 gd_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8 gl_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8 gv_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8 he_IL.UTF-8 UTF-8 hr_HR.UTF-8 UTF-8 hsb_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8 hu_HU.UTF-8 UTF-8 id_ID.UTF-8 UTF-8 is_IS.UTF-8 UTF-8 it_CH.UTF-8 UTF-8 it_IT.UTF-8 UTF-8 iw_IL.UTF-8 UTF-8 ja_JP.UTF-8 UTF-8 ka_GE.UTF-8 UTF-8 kk_KZ.UTF-8 UTF-8 kl_GL.UTF-8 UTF-8 ko_KR.UTF-8 UTF-8 ku_TR.UTF-8 UTF-8 kw_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8 lg_UG.UTF-8 UTF-8 lt_LT.UTF-8 UTF-8 lv_LV.UTF-8 UTF-8 mg_MG.UTF-8 UTF-8 mi_NZ.UTF-8 UTF-8 mk_MK.UTF-8 UTF-8 ms_MY.UTF-8 UTF-8 mt_MT.UTF-8 UTF-8 nb_NO.UTF-8 UTF-8 nl_BE.UTF-8 UTF-8 nl_NL.UTF-8 UTF-8 nn_NO.UTF-8 UTF-8 oc_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8 om_KE.UTF-8 UTF-8 pl_PL.UTF-8 UTF-8 pt_BR.UTF-8 UTF-8 pt_PT.UTF-8 UTF-8 ro_RO.UTF-8 UTF-8 ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8 ru_UA.UTF-8 UTF-8 sk_SK.UTF-8 UTF-8 sl_SI.UTF-8 UTF-8 so_DJ.UTF-8 UTF-8 so_KE.UTF-8 UTF-8 so_SO.UTF-8 UTF-8 sq_AL.UTF-8 UTF-8 st_ZA.UTF-8 UTF-8 sv_FI.UTF-8 UTF-8 sv_SE.UTF-8 UTF-8 tg_TJ.UTF-8 UTF-8 th_TH.UTF-8 UTF-8 tl_PH.UTF-8 UTF-8 tr_CY.UTF-8 UTF-8 tr_TR.UTF-8 UTF-8 uk_UA.UTF-8 UTF-8 wa_BE.UTF-8 UTF-8 xh_ZA.UTF-8 UTF-8 yi_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 zh_CN.UTF-8 UTF-8 zh_HK.UTF-8 UTF-8 zh_SG.UTF-8 UTF-8 zh_TW.UTF-8 UTF-8 zu_ZA.UTF-8 UTF-8"

# GD, Imagick
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    locales locales-all \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    nginx \
    imagemagick \
    cron \
    ghostscript && \
    #
    # Locales
    #
    echo '' >> /usr/share/locale/locale.alias \
    && temp="${ADDITIONAL_LOCALES%\"}" \
    && temp="${temp#\"}" \
    && for i in ${temp}; do sed -i "/$i/s/^#//g" /etc/locale.gen; done \
    && locale-gen && \
    #
    # PHP Extensions
    #
    export CFLAGS="$PHP_CFLAGS" CPPFLAGS="$PHP_CPPFLAGS" LDFLAGS="$PHP_LDFLAGS" && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && \
    docker-php-ext-configure intl && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd intl && \
    pecl install imagick && \
    docker-php-ext-enable imagick intl

COPY . /var/www/html/
COPY --from=vendor /app/vendor/ /var/www/html/vendor/
COPY ./docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY ./docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY ./docker/www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY ./docker/image-magic-policy.xml /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
COPY ./docker/app-cron.txt /app-cron.txt
COPY ./docker/entrypoint.sh /

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**And this is my entrypoint:**

```
#!/bin/bash
crontab /app-cron.txt &
cron -f &
service nginx start &
docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm
```